# Wave function of the universe - universes similar to ours

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

[image]

According to this image, the first peak in the graph corresponds to our universe while the other peaks correspond to other, less probable universes. But what do points slightly right (or left, doesn't matter) from the point corresponding to our universe (red/orange lines I drew in the graph) represent? Do they correspond to universes similar but not identical to our universe? If so, many universes similar to our universe (but not identical) are much more probable than universes at other peaks.

I know that the question is quite basic but I'm just trying to grasp the basics for a school project. (Hawking Hartle wave function of the universe)

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: That picture does not contain any physics.

Comment: I understand why you'd say that and I'm sure the picture isn't exact, but I'm talking about the general idea behind it.

Comment: I would suggest that you pick a school project that you can actually understand. Cosmology is way advanced. Try something with electricity or light or maybe an experiment that repeats one of the major scientific milestones with modern means. We can help with that, if you want help, that is.

Comment: Similar but slightly less probable. But where is this image from?

Comment: I found it on the following website: http://web.uvic.ca/~jtwong/Hartle-Hawking.htm Thank you for your answer.